# Can we set different flowlayout in different sections within a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, flowlayout

[Here is the picture for explanation http://childhoodgamedev.qiniudn.com/xincheng_demo.png](http://childhoodgamedev.qiniudn.com/xincheng_demo.png)

## Question Description

In section 0, the flowlayout is common, like a grid, in section 1, the flowlayout is circular (They are in a UICollectionView).

## The Target

With the users' scrolling, the first part is grid flowlayout, the second part is a custom and more complex flowlayout.

Can we implement this? If not, any one good ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar Problem, do you have any Solution for this?

Comment: Finally, I used another UICollectionView or simple UIView as the section2's cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ChildhoodAndy solved his problem, but for future readers this is probably a good candidate for a `UIPageViewController` using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.  Each page would be its own `UICollectionViewController` with whatever custom layout is needed.

Comment: how does this pagecontroller solve anything.. i need a both views to be simultaneously visible, and not discretely. as one page only at a time. half of both can be visible.. had this answer not been marked, i would have been looking at a more accurate answer.. anyways if someone finds then please reply