# Implement two CollectionView Layouts in one UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Someone already asked this here ([Can we set different flowlayout in different sections within a UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244051/can-we-set-different-flowlayout-in-different-sections-within-a-uicollectionview))..... but no one has responded and I have too little reputation to comment and bump the post.

I'm using a collectionView to sort of emulate a tableView, with the first few cells stretching across the width of the screen. However I'm hoping to create a second section and have the layout change into more of a waterfall effect, similar to Pinterest. I have the layout for both sections already made, I'm just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to implement two layouts at the same time.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create two collection views and assign FirstCollectionViewFlowLayout() to your first collectionView, and SecondCollectionViewFlowLayout() to the second.

```
let firstFlowLayout = FirstCollectionViewFlowLayout()
let firstCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, 
        collectionViewLayout: firstFlowLayout)
// and 
let secondFlowLayout = SecondCollectionViewFlowLayout()
let secondCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, 
        collectionViewLayout: secondFlowLayout)
```

Then if you have any differences in content, you would probably need some conditional in other functions, it would depend on you further implementation.

Comment: You're saying, just put two separate collection views on one view controller yeah?

Comment: Considering, that you said you want two layouts at the same time, and showed similar example, I think it makes sense to have two collection views, both looking and functioning a bit differently. Do you want to achieve something else?

Comment: Well it will just require some refactoring of what I have already. Currently I have a UICollectionViewController xib file in my storyboard that can only have on collection view on it. I guess my question was more if it's possible to use that predetermined collection viewcontroller with two layouts. As it stands if I use two collection views I'll have to move all those ui elements onto a standard ViewController with two collection views on that.

Comment: I think its normal for more complex UI to add few UICollectionView or UITableView, if only it makes sense depending on the purpose. Speaking about two layout in one.. Well, as if you can do custom flow layout class, maybe it would be possible to modify it in a away to match what you want. Also, you probably could just change layout for the collection view at specific moment and reload collection view, but not sure it is worth the hassle.