# Different CollectionViewFlowLayout for different section ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewlayout, flowlayout

I am facing an issue related to `uicollectionview`.
I want to implement two section of collectionview with two different flow layout.
I am already having one section where showing list of items with a customflowlayout. Now I want to add one more section and want to add some different flowlayout for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your flowlayout delegate for collection view, you can try something like this-

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if(indexPath.section == 0){

     }else{

     }
}
```

Comment: @LrLearn, this method will just return the CGSize but I want different custom flowlayout.           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244051/can-we-set-different-flowlayout-in-different-sections-within-a-uicollectionview